# Emacs soft line wrap at word boundary

Tags: emacs

How can I have emacs set to move the the last word at the 80 character mark?

What I mean is this:

Instead of

```
ran/
ge
```

I would like emacs to place the whole word range on the next line at the 80 character mark.

Right now emacs will type past 80 characters and and cut the word at the terminal edge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a [Long Lines mode](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/LongLines) that handles this. Emacs 22 comes with long lines mode, and 23.1 has word wrapping built into the engine; earlier versions can use [this elisp script](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/longlines.el).

Comment: @Michael Mrozek is there a way for the long lines to auto indent to the correct indention level?

Comment: I don't know anything about long lines, I was just trying to make the answer less dependent on the link